# Perl Interacting With Terminal

Tags: multithreading, perl, terminal

I'm not sure if what I am trying to do is possible, and I'm fairly new to perl so I'd appreciate any help.

My perl application will use system() to issue commands to Perforce that will create a devel/workspace, integrate, sync, etc.  But obviously I can't integrate until my devel is created, and I can't sync unless some condition is met, so on and so forth. Also when my code is synced and I run it, I'm not sure how to tell if it finished or not either.

So I'm wondering how to say (slack pseudo code):
system(create my devel);
wait until devel created
system(integrate blah);
wait until integration complete
system (launch test);
wait until test complete;

etc...

I looked at other questions and saw the possibility of using forks, but I am not familiar with how to code that in this context.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Normally, the `system` command in Perl will wait until the command you asked it to run has completed. This would work exactly the same as if you entered the command at a shell prompt, the program would run and the shell prompt would appear only when the command has completed whatever it is doing.

Comment: Curious what you mean by "normally"? Also what if that process requires me to interact with it? Does that change anything?  If you are familiar with perforce (or other revision control software) and you are resolving you have to provide it with input to say accept theirs, or yours, or merged, etc.

Comment: If the process waits for you to interact with it, then you can do so. Your Perl script won't continue running until whatever you called has finished. I say "normally" because it is possible to run a process that puts itself in the background and returns to your Perl script immediately, but the processes you're running aren't likely to do that.

Comment: Oh so in cases where I want parallel processing I'd do what your suggesting. So for example, refering again to perforce, if I wanted to sync 2 devels in parallel (because it takes quite a while), how might I do that? not sure if I should make that a new question.

Comment: Depending on your OS, you might be able to put a command in the background by appending a `&` to the end of the command line. So for example, `system("p4 sync &");` Can't promise this will do exactly what you want though.

Comment: Thanks a lot! :)
I'll get it working sequentially and then give the "&" a try and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

Perforce has a free Perl module downloadable from http://www.perforce.com/downloads/Perforce/20-User?qt-perforce_downloads_step_3=6#qt-perforce_downloads_step_3#52, with documentation at http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r12.1/manuals/p4script/02_perl.html#1047731.

But it sounds like you need more experience with Perl multiprogramming and IPC. Have you read [the Camel book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596004927.do)?